# I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error due to parsing int. But I need to parse that int?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

The program needs to execute with no arguments and with arguments. The program does different things depending on the inputs at the command line. Here is the code, line 94 is causing the problem where I have parsed int a (int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);)

But I have to parse that int in order to execute the program with five or more command line arguments.

Here is the code, it's long, but the problem is at line 94:

```
class CommandArgsOrNot{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int clargs = args.length; 
        if (clargs==0) {
            System.out.print(" "); 
            System.out.println("Hello"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
                }
            System.out.println("World !!"); 
        }

        if (clargs==1) {
            String s = args[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                }
            System.out.println(s); 
            }
        }

        if (clargs==2) {
            System.out.println("ARGUMENT 1:" + " " + (args[0])); 
            System.out.println("ARGUMENT 2:" + " " + (args[1])); 
        }

        if (clargs==3) {
        final int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        final int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        final int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 

        if (a * b == c) {
            System.out.println("1*2=3"); 
        }
        else if (a * c == b) {
        System.out.println("1*3=2");
        }
        else if (b * a == c) {
        System.out.println("2*1=3");
        }
        else if (b * c == a) {
        System.out.println("2*3=1");
        }
        else if (c * a == b) {
        System.out.println("3*1=2"); 
        }
        else if (c * b == a) {
        System.out.println("3*2=1");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("None"); 
        }
        System.out.println(); 
        }

        if (args.length == 4) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
        int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);  
        if (a == b && a == c && a == d) {
            System.out.println("1"); 
        }
        else if (a != b && b != c && c != d) {
            System.out.println("4");
        }
        else if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if (c == d && a != b) {
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        else if (b == c) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if (a == b && a == c) {
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        else if (d == c && d == b) {
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        else if (a == d) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if (a == c && b == d) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        else if (a == d && b != c) {
        System.out.println("3");
        }
        }

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        long answer = 1;
        long result = 0; 
        if (a < 0) {
            for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                answer *=  Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        else if (a == 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(result); 
        }
        else if (a == 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(result); 
        }
        else if (a == 2) {
            for(int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 != 0){
                answer += Integer.parseInt(args[i]); 
                } 

            }
            System.out.println(answer); 
        }
        else if (a == 3) {
            for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (i % 3 != 0) {
                answer += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(answer); 
        } 
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` - Why do you parse args[0] without checking if it's available? In the rest of your code you check for `args.length` before accessing elements of that array.

Comment: Try to indent your code for readability.

Comment: Sidenote, most of the IDE are now highlighting these kind of obvious issues. I would advise you to use wether IntelliJ or Eclipse with ReSharper or SonarLint to spot and fix these things with ease. (These errors doesn't even need a code analysis plugin tho, it's marked as warning/error directly by the IDE)

Comment: Additionally, you can change the if conditions to switch.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the program by using `return` keywords if you didn't pass any parameter to your `Java` program.

eg:

```
 if (clargs==0) {
            System.out.print(" "); 
            System.out.println("Hello"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
                }
            System.out.println("World !!"); 

            return;
        } //please note that there is also many alternative ways to control your program.
```

But, the main idea is that you should not parse any other `args[..]` value to `int` if your `agrs[..]` value is equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your output is-

```
 Hello
   World !!
```

and after this you got an error.
This is because you have accessed `int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0])` 0th argument without checking its existence and if no argument is provided to it then it throws the error.

Check existence before accessing.

Answer (score 0):

While accessing the array element its  index ensure the following.

> The array is not null
>
> The index you are trying to access is within the array size.

In your code add the condition before accessing the args[0] like shown below:

```
  if(clargs!=0) int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

als try to declare the int a before this condition and define here to avoid further errors.

**Full code:**

```
class VariousCases 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            final int clargs = args.length; 
            if (clargs==0) 
            {
                System.out.print(" "); 
                System.out.println("Hello"); 
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                }
                System.out.println("World !!"); 
            }
    
            if (clargs==1)
            {
                String s = args[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(" "); 
                    }
                System.out.println(s); 
                }
            }
    
            if (clargs==2) 
            {
                System.out.println("ARGUMENT 1:" + " " + (args[0])); 
                System.out.println("ARGUMENT 2:" + " " + (args[1])); 
            }
    
            if (clargs==3) 
            {
                final int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                final int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                final int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
    
                if (a * b == c) {
                    System.out.println("1*2=3"); 
                }
                else if (a * c == b) {
                    System.out.println("1*3=2");
                }
                else if (b * a == c) {
                    System.out.println("2*1=3");
                }
                else if (b * c == a) {
                    System.out.println("2*3=1");
                }
                else if (c * a == b) {
                    System.out.println("3*1=2"); 
                }
                else if (c * b == a) {
                    System.out.println("3*2=1");
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("None"); 
                }
                System.out.println(); 
            }
    
            if (args.length == 4) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
                int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                int d = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);  
                if (a == b && a == c && a == d) {
                    System.out.println("1"); 
                }
                else if (a != b && b != c && c != d) {
                    System.out.println("4");
                }
                else if (a == b) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                else if (c == d && a != b) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                }
                else if (b == c) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                else if (a == b && a == c) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                }
                else if (d == c && d == b) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                }
                else if (a == d) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                else if (a == c && b == d) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                else if (a == d && b != c) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                }
            }
    
            // Add the condition to check the arguments length is greater and the index you are trying to access is within the range of the array length
            if(clargs!=0)
                int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            long answer = 1;
            long result = 0; 
            if (a < 0) {
                for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                    answer *=  Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
            else if (a == 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(result); 
            }
            else if (a == 1) {
                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    result += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(result); 
            }
            else if (a == 2) {
                for(int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 != 0){
                    answer += Integer.parseInt(args[i]); 
                    } 
    
                }
                System.out.println(answer); 
            }
            else if (a == 3) {
                for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 3 != 0) {
                    answer += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(answer); 
            } 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line 94 is called without any checks on the size of args. Try to check if the size is ok before trying to access the array cell.

```
if(args.length > 1){
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    //What you want to do with you value.
}
```